# C Asterisk Operator Using

Tags: c, pointers, implicit-conversion, sizeof, pointer-arithmetic

im trying to learn pointers and im confused in second line, can someone explain how it works?

if we suppose 'a' base address is 100

```
  int a[3][3] = {6, 2, 5, 0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 8};
  printf("%p \n", a+1); // output is gonna be 112
  printf("%p \n", *(a+1));// still output is gonna be 112
```

How does the pointer arithmetic and the dereference operator (*) work in the second line of code? Why does the printf statement printf("%p \n", *(a+1)); output the memory address 112 instead of the integer value at that address? Thanks in advance

Comment: The second line (the one in the middle) doesn't have a `*` in it.

Comment: @ScottHunter Actually it does, i meant that part in the printf *(a+1)

Comment: I would think the output will be `10C` or `0x10C` not `112`.

Comment: the same way as writting `int a[1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1] = {1};` and then referring to the same pointer with a, a[0], a[0][0], a[0][0][0], ..., but it's a bit more straight-forward to demonstrate it :)

Comment: The `*` is in the *third* line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that for any array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is *exactly* the same as `*(a + i)`.

If we apply it to your example, then `a + 1` is a pointer to the second element of the array `a`. It's the same as `&a[1]`.

And `*(a + 1)` is `a[1]`, which is an array and therefore will decay to a pointer to its first element, meaning that `a[1]` is the same as `&a[1][0]`.

While these two pointers, `&a[1]` and `&a[1][0]`, have different types, they both point to the same location. Which is very easy to see once we draw it out, with the pointers added:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[0][2] | a[1][0] | ... (not relevant) |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
                              ^
                              |- &a[1]
                              |- &a[1][0]
```

---

To expand on the different types, `&a[1]` is a pointer to an array of three `int` elements, or `int (*)[3]`.

The other pointer, `&a[1][0]`, is a pointer to a single `int` element, and therefore have the type `int *`.

Answer (score 1):

An array designator used in expression with rare exceptions is converted to pointer to its first element.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

In the provided code snippet the array `a` is declared like

```
int a[3][3] = {6, 2, 5, 0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 8};
```

So in the expression `a + 1` the array designator `a` is converted to pointer of the type `int ( * )[3]`. That is it is a pointer to the first element ("row") of the array. Thus the expression `a + 1` points to the second element ("row") of the type `int[3]` of the array.  The value of the address produced of the expression `a + 1` differs from the address of the first element of the array by the value `sizeof( int[3] )`. If `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4` then the difference between the addresses if equal to `3 * sizeof( int )` that is to `12`.

As for this expression `*( a + 1 )` then dereferencing the expression `a + 1` it yields the second element of the array of the type `int[3]`. Used as an expression in the call of `printf` the array designator `*( a + 1 )` having the type `int[3]` again is implicitly converted to pointer of the type `int *` to its first element. The addresses of the first element of the second "row" and of the second "row" itself are equal each other though they have different types.

For example these calls of `printf`:

```
printf( "Address of &a = %p\n", ( void * )&a );
printf( "Address of a = %p\n", ( void * )a );
printf( "Address of &a[0] = %p\n", ( void * )&a[0] );
printf( "Address of a[0] = %p\n", ( void * )a[0] );
printf( "Address of &a[0][0] = %p\n", ( void * )&a[0][0] );
```

will output the same address value though types of the used expressions are different. The types of the expressions (taking into account the implicit conversion of array designators to pointers to their first elements) are (from top to bottom):

```
&a       -> int ( * )[3][3]
a        -> int ( * )[3]
&a[0]    -> int ( * )[3]
a[0]     -> int *
&a[0][0] -> int *
```